# Where do you place your (view specific) classes in an ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, directory-structure

Our Site is getting bigger now and we have to apply some structuring to the web application.

Currently it looks like this:

```
- App_Themes
- Content (NuGet, untouched)
  - themes
    - base
- Libs
- Pages
  - A
    - PageOfA1.aspx
    - PageOfA2.aspx
  - B
    - PageOfB1.aspx
    - PageOfB2.aspx
  - LogOn.aspx
  - Site.master
- Resources
  - Images
  - Reports
  - Scripts
  - Styles
- Scripts (NuGet, untouched)
- UserControls
```

I´d like to see some of your directory structures and especially I want to know: Where should we place our view specific class files (*.cs) that are beeing used within the code behind of the *.aspx pages?
Since now we were relatively happy with placing them inside the corresponding *.aspx.cs files because of the physical nearness.

But we're about to activate the StyleCop rule that enforces a single class per file.
So where should I place these files?

I´m consciously not telling you my ideas because I´m unhappy with all of them and if they would match one of mine I will live with that unhappy feeling concerning that solution anyway.

Comment: what do you mean by "raw *.cs files"? Are you talking about `.aspx.cs` or `.cs`?

Comment: No, sorry. I mean pure view specific class files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a seperation of concern. Have a project for your data access, one for your domain models, one for services and one for testing.

Check this link for information on N-Tier architecture - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430014/N-Tier-Architecture-and-Tips

Comment: This is already the case. But what I´m talking about are no real "BusinessObjects". They are more "ViewModels".

Comment: Example: I have a class WeatherData and I don´t want to place this class within our BusinessObjects project. So I have to store it in a folder in the web application project. The question: Where should this folder be stored within the structure and how to name it.

Comment: A further example: Web specific helper classes.

Comment: I tend to just create a folder called "Helpers" in the web app and store it in there.